# PagedList appending complete page data in GET request

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, pagedlist

I am trying to implement PagedList for my asp.net MVC page. I have created modal with data and created StaticPagedList with that. Here is my Controller:

```
        objPvm.NotificationsList = objUtil.getWorkGroupRecords(Session["SelectedWrkGrp"].ToString(), objPvm);
        objPvm.PagedNList = new StaticPagedList<FinalizeNotificationVM>(objPvm.NotificationsList, objPvm.qrConfig.PageIndex, objPvm.qrConfig.PageSize, objPvm.qrConfig.TotalRecords);
```

Here is my View:

```
<div class="text-center" data-res-target="#searchResults">
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model.PagedNList, Pg => Url.Action(Model.ViewName, new { Pg, nStatus = Model.NotificationStatus }),
    new PagedListRenderOptions() { Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded, DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = true })
</div>
```

When I am trying to pagenate while navigating through pagedList, I am getting following error:

***HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found***
*The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.*

Here are screen prints, related to Paged list
http://postimg.org/image/vu280etwz/
http://postimg.org/image/t190gdtkj/

Please help, in resolving this. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow your entire `NotificationsList` collection is being put into the query string. Most likely this is the result of submitting a form via GET (a search box perhaps?). This is what's causing the error as there's an upward limit to the data you can attach to a query string and you've exceeded it. You'll need to find a different way to handle your form submittal without requiring all this data to go into the query string.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I gave only two querystring through PagedList - **Pg** and **nStatus**  Even though I am NOT posting page data, do you know why it is posting to server in GET request.

Comment: I can't say. There's not enough code here to determine what's causing this. In particular it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the actual PagedList stuff here.